# implement aspectj logging inside java timer

Tags: java, spring-mvc, timer, aspectj, aspect

I have a method that throws IOException which is called from a java timer run().Since the run() doesn't return any checked exceptions and I am using AspectJ for logging, how do I log the exception in aspectj?

This is my code:

`timer = new Timer();`
`

```
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            for (OidTypes oidType : typesList) {

                try {
                    valueIncrementOperation(oidType);//------this method throws exception
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    System.out.println("Error occured inside Timer : "
                            + e.getMessage());

                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = null;
                }

            }
```

`
I am forced to use try/catch for now. What are my options?

Comment: try calling e.getCause()

Comment: @PeterQuiring: I am trying to get rid of try/catch block, so where do I call that from since aspectj cant intercept the run().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to pack the IOException into an unchecked exception, the real exception will be the cause of the exception you catch in the advice.

The simplest is to take RuntimeException.

```
public void doTimerJob() {
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                throw new IOException("file not found");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                timer.cancel();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }, new Date(), 2000);
}
```

Then you could try the following:

Create a point cut for TimerTask#run

```
pointcut timerTaskRun() : execution(public * java.util.TimerTask.run(..) );
```

and an advice for after throwing a RuntimeException

```
after() throwing(RuntimeExceptione) : timerTaskRun() {
    System.out.println("log and rethrow " + e.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

This will re-throw the exception after logging it.

If you want to log and swallow the exception you could write an around advice

```
Object around() : timerTaskRun() {
    Object o;
    try {
        o = proceed();   
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("log and swallow " + e.getCause().getMessage());
        o = null;
    }
    return o;
}
```

Note that you should only have only one of the advices, either `after throwing` or `around` not both.

But you may not want to advice all `TimerTask#run` calls along with all `RuntimeException`s. In this case you should create own types which you should use in the point cut and the advices.

"Unchecked" IOException

```
public class IOExceptionUnchecked extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public IOExceptionUnchecked(IOException e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

Custom TimerTask

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask  {
    Timer owner = null; 
    public MyTimerTask(Timer timer) {this.owner = timer;}
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            throw new IOException("file not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            owner.cancel();
            throw new IOExceptionUnchecked(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Point cut

```
pointcut timerTaskRun() : execution(public * com.example.MyTimerTask.run(..) );
```

after throwing advice:

```
after() throwing(IOExceptionUnchecked e) : timerTaskRun() {
    System.out.println("log and rethrow " + e.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

Or around advice

```
Object around() : timerTaskRun() {
    Object o;
    try {
        o = proceed();   
    } catch(IOExceptionUnchecked e) {
        System.out.println("log and swallow " + e.getCause().getMessage());
        o = null;
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much bro.. appreciate the time and effort you put to post the code and go over all the details...i will definitely try to implement it...thanks again...

Comment: @decentguy you're welcome! Hope it helps you find a way to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get rid of the try/catch block because `IOException` is a checked exception and `TimerTask#run` is declared not to throw any checked Exception. Also you have additional logic in the catch block to cancel the timer.

The nearest thing you can you is wrap the `IOException` to a `RuntimeException` and re-throw it.

```
   catch(IOException){
        timer.cancel();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Even by doing so, the exception and stack trace would not be logged by AspectJ.
To do so, you need to use a container(like Spring) to create the `TimerTask` instance and wrap it with AspectJ interceptor.

Comment: thanks for the comment and I am using Spring MVC. How do I wrap the `TimerTask` instance with aspectj?

Comment: There are several steps: 1) move the anonymous class to a first level class. 2) managed the bean with spring, either by annotation or put it into spring context file, note you may need to use a `prototype` scope. 3) apply aspectj related annotation